# How to filter date from textfield in swift

Tags: json, swift, date, filter

this is my array

```
   var servicesArray = [ServicesModel]()
  servicesArray.append(.init(header: openData.get_service_category?.category, title: openData.request_title, date: openData.from_date, location: openData.location, gender: openData.gender, id: openData.id))
```

this is my service call: here if i add `from_date` date from search textfield then i need to show only the date contain tableview cell should show

```
   func postedServicesCall(){
    
    let param = ["from_date" : fromDateTextField.text, "to_date" : ""]
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param as [String : Any], method: .post, loaderNeed: false, loadingButton: nil, needViewHideShowAfterLoading: nil, vc: self, url: CommonUrl.posted_requests, isTokenNeeded: true, isErrorAlertNeeded: true, isSuccessAlertNeeded: false, actionErrorOrSuccess: nil, fromLoginPageCallBack: nil) { [weak self] (resp) in
        
        self?.postedServicesData = Posted_services_base_model(dictionary: resp.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
        
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return servicesArray.count
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ServicesTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ServicesTableViewCell
    
    cell.headerLabel.text = servicesArray[indexPath.row].header
    cell.serviceTitle.text = servicesArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateLabel.text = servicesArray[indexPath.row].date
    cell.locationLabel.text = servicesArray[indexPath.row].location
    
    return cell
}
```

this is searchbtn:

```
@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if fromDateTextField.text != nil{
        
    }
}
```

how to show filtered date contain tableview cells, please do help with code

Comment: What is it you want to filter, the servicesArray I presume? But how, what is the property you want to filter on!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson with `from_date` i need to filter.. which will come from `fromDateTextField.text`

Comment: I already understood that part. But I don’t understand _what_ you want to filter and how from_date should be used.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i to dont know.. first time i am working.. with filter i think `servicesArray` `date`